# How do I use autograd for a separate function independent of backpropagate in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, autograd

I have two variables, `x` and `theta`. I am trying to minimise my loss with respect to `theta` only, but as part of my loss function I need the derivative of a different function (`f`) with respect to `x`. This derivative itself is not relevant to the minimisation, only its output. However, when implementing this in PyTorch I am getting a Runtime error.

A minimal example is as follows:

```py
# minimal example of two different autograds
import torch

from torch.autograd.functional import jacobian
def f(theta, x):
    return torch.sum(theta * x ** 2)

def df(theta, x):
    J = jacobian(lambda x: f(theta, x), x)
    return J

# example evaluations of the autograd gradient
x = torch.tensor([1., 2.])
theta = torch.tensor([1., 1.], requires_grad = True)

# derivative should be 2*theta*x (same as an analytical)
with torch.no_grad():
    print(df(theta, x))
    print(2*theta*x)
```

> tensor([2., 4.])

> tensor([2., 4.])

```py
# define some arbitrary loss as a fn of theta
loss = torch.sum(df(theta, x)**2)
loss.backward()
```

gives the following error

> RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

If I provide an analytic derivative (`2*theta*x`), it works fine:

```py
loss = torch.sum((2*theta*x)**2)
loss.backward()
```

Is there a way to do this in PyTorch? Or am I limited in some way?

Let me know if anyone needs any more details.

**PS**

I am imagining the solution is something similar to the way that *JAX* does autograd, as that is what I am more familiar with. What I mean here is that in *JAX* I believe you would just do:

```py
from jax import grad
df = grad(lambda x: f(theta, x))
```

and then `df` would just be a function that can be called at any point. But is PyTorch the same? Or is there some conflict within `.backward()` that causes this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyTorch's [`jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html) does not create a computation graph unless you explicitely ask for it

```
J = jacobian(lambda x: f(theta, x), x, create_graph=True)
```

.. with `create_graph` argument.

The documentation is quite clear about it

> create_graph (bool, optional) – If True, the Jacobian will be computed in a differentiable manner

Comment: Yes I have looked into this, but I didn't really understand. I think this means that I don't want to use the `create_graph` argument, because I don't want it to be included in my `.backward()` call. In this case, why does it give me an error? I don't understand the error message.

Comment: What you are trying to do is basically differentiating through the *operations of a jacobian*. In that case, you need to have them built as a graph. Without `create_graph`, jacobian won't create a graph hanging from `loss` (you can check `loss.grad_fn` is empty - hence the error)